# map.pool running out of memory - when to close and join

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am parallelizing ingestion and analysis of a dataset using Pool.map. However I keep running into `'an out of memory'` error. This is despite me working on a cluster with 100GB of memory and working with a compressed file of ~25gb (the uncompressed is likely larger than 100GB). I believe I am running out of memory because I am joining and closing processes incorrectly i.e. All the chunks are being stored in memory. Here is my code:

```
    ##load df 
    df_chunk =  pd.read_csv(f'{file}', sep = '\t' ,  chunksize = 10000)
    ## parallel process
    pool = Pool(16)
    processed_results = pool.map(conduct_analysis, df_chunk)
    ## merge all results together
    df_all = reduce(merge_results, processed_results)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

With the following function definition for the analysis:

```
def conduct_analysis(df):
    ##dictionary to store results
    pvalue = {}
    ##clean columns
    df = df.replace('./.', '0/0')
    ##run analysis
    for group in df.groupby(pos):
        sample = pd.DataFrame(group[1]['age_of_onset'])
        #ANOVA test
        f_val, p_val = stats.f_oneway(*sample)
   p_value[pos] = p_val[0]

   return p_value
```

Note `reduce(merge results)` just takes in the mapped results and joins them together.

I can provide output examples too but i believe this is not necessary for my issue. I believe I am running out of memory as the function calls are not being closed when the new one is being opened. is there a way to close the chunk but still retain the output? If I run this code in a for loop one chunk at a time I do not get such an error.

Thanks!

Comment: Note that `multiprocessing` *only* runs on cores of the local machine. It does *not* use a cluster.

Comment: Yes - what i mean is I submit the job to a SLURM cluster. It then schedules to run the script on 1 core with 16 CPU's and 100GB. The point I am making is the resources should be enough to run the job.

Comment: Perhaps instead of using `map`, use `Pool.imap`, which returns instead of a list an iterator. Each iteration of the iterator returns the next result returned by `conduct_analysis` whereas `map` returns you a list of all results and would take far more memory. if `reduce` is `functools.reduce`, then `processed_results` could be instead that iterator returned by `imap`. You may want to use a *chunksize* argument with `imap`. Unlike `map`, which will provide a "reasonable" *chunksize* value if none is specified, `imap` will end up using a *chunksize* of 1, which might be less than optimal.

Comment: Having to transport each "chunk" to the workers could take a lot of resources. Having each worker read (part of) the CSV might be more efficient.

Comment: thanks @Booboo I will try imap. re chunksize - i am already loading in chunks via pandas - shall i just match the chunksize with imap?

Comment: @RolandSmith How would you suggest I have each worker read a chunk?

Comment: @AE93 Use the `skiprows` and `nrows` parameters of `read_csv`. Create a list of suitable values of `skiprows` and `map` over that.

Comment: If you are using `map` then the way it computes a *chunksize* when none is specified is to take the number of tasks being submitted, i.e. the length of the passed iterable, divided by 4 * the pool size.  To follow suit you would need to estimate how many chunks you will end up with by specifying `read_csv` with its *chunksize* value. Of course, the larger the *chunksize* you go with the greater the memory utilization. You could also decrease the `read_csv` *chunksize* and end up with more, smaller chunks.

Comment: @RolandSmith your suggestion worked very well! Thanks a lot